# How to order month with no aphabetically?

Tags: postgresql

help me to solve that.
I want to order month with no alphabetically on PostgreSQL.

This is my code :

```
  SELECT to_char(closed_date,'Month') AS "month" , 
  count(card_number) AS "total"
  FROM c_card_status_history
  where extract(year from closed_date) = 2018
  GROUP BY "month" order by "month"
```

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: What is the actual result you are getting currently? Which is the result that you really want to see? How do they differ?

Comment: Most importantly: What is the ordering you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to preserve the `closed_date` as a date (or timestamp) so that you can order on it. To do that you can group on `date_trunc('month', closed_date)` and use that as the order by expression:

```
SELECT to_char(date_trunc('month', closed_date), 'Month') AS "month", 
       count(card_number) AS "total"
FROM c_card_status_history
where extract(year from closed_date) = 2018
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', closed_date)
ORDER BY date_trunc('month', closed_date)
```

grouping by `date_trunc('month', closed_date)` will achieve the same as your grouping by your `to_char()` expression because you also limit the result to only months from 2018.

Comment: Wow, it's great...
Thank you !